Lidar data rotates when robot rotates
I am developing a differential drive robot for autonomous navigation tasks, and while running in gazebo, I see that in rviz while running nav2, if the robot turns or rotates in place, then the laser scan data also rotates with it, which makes the robot think that a obstacle is there while in actual it is a free path for robot to go.
Maybe it is due to odometry of the robot but I was not able to find any problem with it,
Attaching video url for better understanding...
I am using ros2 humble on ubuntu 22.04
Let me know if you want any other details.

isn't the lidar attached to the robot, i.e., isn't it correct for it to rotate when the robot rotates? Could you please state your question explicitly?

You can see in the video, lidar scan shows a obstacle at the end of the hallway where in actual there isn't one. Also when the robot turns, the lidar scan also displaces and shows obstacles where there isn't one, shouldn't it remain at the same place as obstacles. Robot moves so lidar will move too, but laser scan should get obstacles at same points in space right?
